# How to make multiple lines of p tag & text show as a neat table

Tags: html, css, styles

I have HTML text in format like:

```
<p>Something</p> Some other text here.
<p>Something</p> Some other text here.
<p>Something</p> Some other text here.
```

Now when I display it in browser it shows up like:

`Something`

`Some other text here.`

`Something`

`Some other text here.`

`Something`

`Some other text here.`

But, I want to show it in a neat table.

Like:

`Something     Some text here.`

`Something     Some text here.`

`Something     Some text here.`

Is it possible?

EDIT: Sorry guys! I think its not possible. I am going back to work.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with pure css due to the fact that the some other text is not wrapped in an element

Comment: Thank you Pete! Just wanted to know that.

Comment: If you want a `table`... **just use one**. There's no shame...assuming this is tabluar data. Otherwise, perhaps a grid system.

Comment: @Paulie_D No, what if I do not want to? What if I do not have the option to modify the original text? I do not want to overwrite anything, just want a neat display with the options I have.

Comment: And, woooohoooo I am not getting a solution to the problem, but I am getting downvotes because no one can do it. At least the downvoters cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

add some css to your `<p>` tag,

```
p{
  display:inline;
  margin-right:30px;
  }
```

```css
p{
  display:inline;
  margin-right:30px;
  }
```

```html
<p>Something</p> Some other text here.<br> <p>Something</p> Some other text here.<br> <p>Something</p> Some other text here.
```

Comment: Sorry bro! Its now showing everything in same line.

Comment: Yes, very strange, its not working on my page, may be some styles are conflicting.

Comment: @rsharpy, it's because answer has extra br tags

Comment: haha good catch @Pete. I thought it was not working just on my page. #dream I cannot modify the text.